# IntelliJ Idea doesn't place dependencies in External Libraries Folder

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

Currently have a hard times working on one project. While building with maven I'm getting success but when I open the project all classes are red with unresolved dependencies and folder "External Libraries" contains only JDK classes.
Does anyone know what might be the reason of this?
Thanks in advance.

I'm using Intellij Idea 14.0.2 and Maven version 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Enable auto reload for your pom file(s). intelliji doesn't do it automatcally unless you enable it.
To do so, just open a pom file and you'll see a popup that asks you if you to enable auto relaod.

Comment: Thanks for comment but it didn't help

Comment: You might have accidentally removed maven nature from your project. Can you try right clicking the `pom.xml` file and click Maven -> Reimport? It seems like IntelliJ is ignoring the pom.xml file completely.

Comment: For those still facing issues, you can refer to the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442106/intellij-is-not-showing-external-libraries-in-project-tab

Answer (score 0):

Right click on pom.xml > Maven > Reload project