# Intellij is not showing "External Libraries" in Project Tab

Tags: intellij-idea

There is nothing on left. It is a maven project. Why?

[image: IntelliJ]

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244002/104891 helps.

Comment: thanks your answer . I tried  2017.2.1 version. but nothing happened. Should i change some thing in "Project  Structure"?

Comment: Check the logs for exceptions, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: 2017-08-02 00:42:11,714 [ 396152]  ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence
parsed                        :ESC[?2004l
bytes read                    :ESC[ 
2017-08-02 00:42:11,715 [ 396153]  ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Error processing OSC 1;help 
2017-08-02 00:42:11,718 [ 396156]  ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Error processing OSC 1;..ts/work/test1 
2017-08-02 00:42:11,741 [ 396179]  ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence

Comment: This error is not related.

Comment: solved it. I clean up intellij-idea's configuration,caches ,plugins  and try 2017.2.1 version again. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by selecting "Project" as view (by default i had "Project Files"). Hope this helped.

[Project View VS. Project Files view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WyFi.png)

Comment: Thanks, really after switching view it appeared in Project structure -> Artifacts -> new artifact added -> Library files

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same problem and narrowed it down to the following configuration that might have been messed up during the upgrade.

File (on Mac): `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.1/options/projectView.xml`

```xml
<application>
  <component name="ProjectViewSharedSettings">
    <option name="showLibraryContents" value="false" />
    <option name="showMembers" value="true" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Change/remove the `showLibraryContents` entry. This setting is no longer available in the UI, "External Libraries" are always shown.

Comment: Also works with Android Studio of course, though it took me a while to find this answer !

Comment: This works. Maybe it is not located under IntelliJIdea2018.1 but under IdeaIC2018.1

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue on windows, i solved it by

right click on pom.xml > maven > reimport

Then reopen the project, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. If maven re-import does nothing, check your pom.xml for errors and try commenting out the offending ones (marked in red).
2. In Intellij: `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` -> Select Modules and ensure that there is only one module. Delete the other ones.
3. If all else fails:
   In Intellij, Select "Invalidate caches/Restart" -> Close Intellij -> Go to the project folder and delete .idea folder -> Reopen Intellij and "mvn clean install"

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `./idea` directory and re-importing the project worked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it seems I have seen this same kind of thing recently.  Check your module settings (right click on highest level folder - open module settings, or Command-;).  Make sure you have one module if it is a single-POM project, and check the sources, paths, dependencies tabs and make sure they look right.  I think I've seen this once when I created a module manually rather than letting intellij create one for the Maven module automatically.

That "recycle/refresh" icon on the far right pane you show - the Maven project pane - can also sometimes get it to fix things it didn't get right when you initially check out project.