# Android studio is missing “External Libraries” in Project Tab

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to 3.3, I could not find the "External Libraries" folder in the project tab.

Can't find the settings option to get this back on.

Anyone had this issue and was able to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found another SO post which explained how to get it back:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731324

Edit `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio<VERSION>/options/projectView.xml` and set the `showLibraryContents` entry to `true`