# Jar file not getting added in to a external Libraries in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I am trying to work on a spring-security project in which i have added the spring security dependency via pom.xml file.But as my maven completed its build successfully,its not getting added in the external library.
Please find my the screenshots below:

1. pom.xml file:

[image]

2. External Library

[image]

3. Dependencies added after successful maven build :

[image]

Tried to create a new project to check whether the above issues persist there as well,but there its working as expected as i am able to get the required java files.So the issue is only relevant to the above project.

I even tried to do the steps mentioned from the below links apart from the maven life cycle steps,but that also did not work out

[link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206903515-Not-all-Maven-dependencies-appear-in-External-libraries-)

Comment: I got the issue finally,I rearranged the dependencies,The "spring-boot-starter-security" was lying on the bottom which i have brought out on to the top.I am not exactly sure whether this was the genuine reason behind the fix.but it worked!!!

Comment: For those still facing issues, you can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442106/intellij-is-not-showing-external-libraries-in-project-tab/67102413#67102413